# PHP session timeout issue

Tags: php

I am getting a session timeout all the time.

When ever a user is idle for some time, he has to re-login. I want him to login again only if he **closes his browser**. I have not used anything to destroy or unset the session, I only do that in the logout page.

I have set my PHP INI file to set all the session variables. You can browse the Session Variable here at the link.

http://www.providentfeed.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577106/what-php-ini-settings-are-required-to-allow-a-session-to-remain-active-for-approx

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your directions, but I already have set these two parameters(session.cookie_lifetime and session.gc_maxlifetime) to 40 hours. But it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can write the following code in your php file.

```
// Session timeout value in seconds. Let's say we increase it to 24 hours
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 24*60*60);
```

Comment: Naveed thank you for your reply. Actually I tried this before in my PHP code, it did not worked. Then I tried it in PHP.ini file. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

That's standard behavior. If you want the user to be logged in indefinitely, you'll need to create a cookie and check for its presence in the login page. And simply log the user in if the cookie exists.

Comment: Actually it is a big application and not using some MVC so that I can do it easily. I think there will be some solution to keep the session for a couple of hours. Thanks