# Using a prolonged session?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I'm setting up a script that my local pub will use to show users slide shows of images, menus, etc. My URL will accept a key(uuid), from which my script will query the database for the content associated with the key based on a company_id. The site will then just rotate through images via javascript or jquery.

Before serving out the content, I would like to make sure that the session or user is authenticated meaning that there is a valid company_id associated.

I've always used `$_SESSION` variables for web sessions. Since there will be no real need to time out a session, would there be any flags I can set in php.ini to never time out? Or would it be more beneficial to use cookies for this type of work?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5577106/82447

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using a cookie to store a login token for the user with a distant expiry date, so they are auto-logged in.  Preserving `$_SESSION` indefinitely would cause session files to pile up on your server wasting resources on the filesystem. Instead, a cookie can hold some token (non-guessable value) that is associated with the user in your database. Basic information can be retrieved from the database then when the user returns.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `session_start()` the script will try and set a cookie in the users browser containing the session id, there is no need to manually set one holding a "non-guessable value" since that is what the session id is supposed to be anyway.

You can change `session.cookie-lifetime` in the ini file (maybe even with `ini_set()`) to prevent the cookie timing out at the end of the session.

Preserving `$_SESSION` will **not** cause session files to pile up indefinitely. By keeping the session alive the same file will be re-used over and over again (since it is named after the session id), and PHPs built in session garbage collector will clear up dead sessions anyway.

While in general it is a bad idea to make sessions last forever, since it's your local pub, I doubt anyone is going to try and hijack their session. (and even if they did, all they'd get is what's for sunday lunch, right?) :)

**Edit:**
You could also periodically regenerate the session id, to add a bit more security.